# using console.log with conduit

Tags: javascript, firebug, conduit

I'm trying to debug a script written in javascript that runs on a conduit toolbar. for now i'm using simply

```
window.alert("function x is working");
```

but this is very disturbing in case of many alerts as the script grows bigger. i would prefer to write log or debug messages into FireBug or Chrome's console, with:

```
console.log("function x is working");
```

as this is much more reasonable, but this code has no effect when this is ran from a javascript file i include in an html component on a conduit toolbar.
i have really tried to research this and similar issues with conduit toolbar api, but i see they are not really common subjects here on stack.. does anyone know of a forum or a good resource of information for conduit api usage? their official page is a little confusing for me.

really appriciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't get much information on Conduit toolbar API here.
This is a work-around that i thought of, hope this can help others.

```
var writeToConsoleScriptStr = 'console.log("your message here");';
JSInjection(writeToConsoleScriptStr);
```

This is helpful if you need to use other matters related to your page as well, for example using Jquery to run code when tab is focused/blurred. By the way, Both the writing to the console and JQuery for tab-switching events ran on all browsers that i checked, which was a nice touch.
Of course for running Jquery the actual page requires the page to include jquery which you can also achieve by injecting it the same way. (At a certain cost)

i'm hoping this may help somebody.